# Matrix multiplication without copying using operator *

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm using C++.
I want to multiply matrix

```
class mat
{
 mat operator *(const mat& mA,const mat& mB)
}
```

If RVO is ON then I will have direct use of the value calculated in *operator **. But if RVO is OFF I will have to copie the object . RVO is not part of the standard. I want to be sure that every conmpiler will do multiply without coping. What will be the best way to avoid copy of object. My question include C++11,14.

Is there way to rewrite *operator ** to multiply matrixes without coping result, even with RVO OFF.

Comment: Why would you ever disable RVO and copy elision? Can you elaborate on the actual problem you have?

Comment: I want to be sure that on every compiler the behaviour will be same.

Comment: This is unlikely to appear, each compiler compiles the way its designers decided, the sole thing that you may require is that semantic is preserved.

Comment: It seems like you want to do premature optimization. Don't. First of all make sure your code is readable and maintainable and most importantly *works*. Then if it's not "fast enough" you start to measure and profile to find the bottlenecks. Work primarily on the worst bottlenecks to optimize them, leave the smaller alone. Repeat until it is "fast enough". Remember to document the optimizations, and the code you refactor, because optimization refactoring will make code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev - *I want to be sure that on every compiler the behaviour will be same* -- You cannot guarantee this.  All that is guaranteed is that the final result, whether optimizations are on or off, aggressive or passive, comes out the same.  Compiler manufacturers compete with each other on who can optimize code better, so you have no say in the internals of the "tricks" used by compiler writers on how they've optimized code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I write it bad. I want to be sure that every conmpiler will do multiply without coping.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev -- What is "every compiler"?  You have multiple versions of Visual Studio, multiple versions of gcc, multiple versions of clang, multiple versions of the Intel compiler, and who knows what other compilers are out there.  Are you going to try and make sure every single compiler does optimizations exactly the same way?  The only thing that should concern you is if a compiler produces wrong results, given that the program doesn't have bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to have design, which will allow me without any optimizaion to do multiply without copying the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `C++11` then why not use [Move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [Move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).

The move constructor is called whenever selected by overload resolution, which typically occurs when an object is initialized from rvalue (xvalue or prvalue) of the same type, including

- function return by value.

So, one of these can be used assuming `mat::x` is statically allocated `int`:

```
friend mat&& mat::operator*(const mat &a, const mat &b)
{
    mat *c = new mat();
    c->x = a.x * b.x;
    return std::move(*c);
}

friend mat mat::operator*(const mat &a, const mat &b)
{
    mat c;
    c.x = a.x * b.x;
    return c;
}
```

Also provide the corresponding `move constructor` and `move assignment operator` for `class mat`.

***I want to be sure that every compiler will do multiply without coping. What will be the best way to avoid copy of object.***

Instead of `operator*` use:

```
void mat::Multiplication(const mat &a, const mat &b, mat &result);
{
    result.x = a.x * b.x;
}
```

Comment: I was asking for sth like this, but in the case with move reference you return rvalue reference to mat, I'm not still quite good with rvalie reference. would you mind to extend the code?

Comment: Actualy the main reason for this question was using rvlue reference in this case. 1 up from me

Answer (score 0):

Wait for C++17, where RVO is specified to happen in some cases. Barring that, look at specific details on what your compiler(s) guarantee, which may be more than the standard requires.